# Kotlin fails to inline some bodies

Tags: kotlin, inline

I have an inline function which accepts two lambdas. This function is called in a hotspot of my code and, despite it being inline, thousands of objects are created for the bodies.

What's interesting is commenting out, or replacing the bodies with simple calls like `println`s and everything works perfectly. But for some reason with my specific use, it seems like inline is failing to do its job!

How can I resolve this? And what are the limitations associated with inlining bodies? Is this a bug?

[image]

My use case:

```
fun PlayerSend.sync() = reusable({
    val packet = this

    it.syncMovement(packet)

    reusable({ if (it.updateRequired) it.sync(this) }, {
        packet.bits(8, 0 /* amount of players to update */)
        if (readable > 0) {
            packet.bits(11, 2047).byteAccess() + this
        } else packet.byteAccess()
    })
}, { ses + 81.byte + readable.short + this })
```

The method header:

```
inline fun <R1, R2> reusable(use: ByteBufPacketeer.() -> R1, after: ByteBufPacketeer.() -> R2) {
        val reusables = Reusables.get()
        val count = ReuseablesCount.get()
        ReuseablesCount.set(if (count + 1 >= reusables.size) 0 else count + 1)
        with(reusables[count]) {
            use()
            after()
            clear()
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it depends on your specific use, show the specific use.

Comment: A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. I can't this example to compile when trying to create stubs for the various types, etc.

Comment: could you please replaces all your custom types with standard like `String` or simple defined like `class A`? That way we can build your example and see the problem

Comment: @Jire Could it be possible that you're profiling the code compiled when `reusable` was not an `inline` function?

Comment: I'm working on an MCVE, this problem is very hard to replicate.

Comment: @Ilya I've profiled it multiple times, all with inline. The same results happen every time. Unfortunately the problem is extremely hard to replicate, I believe it has something to do with many-level virtual extension functions.